# How to setup dbaccess for informix?

Tags: informix, dbaccess

We have installed informix client in 64 bit machine. Informix client doesn't include "dbaccess" command. Our application uses "dbaccess" command in many shell scripts. As per the configuration we are not supposed to install server here. Is it possible to download or configure "dbaccess" alone?

Appreciate the support in advance.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standalone 9.40 version [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0406chong/index.html). If this version doesn't works well, you can try to browse the IBM download site or a Google search.